# How to set AMP meta description with functions.hp in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I set the php code for meta description in normal entrys in WP, and I have set an additional php code for AMP template to replicate the same text in the meta description tag but I doný know how to vinculate them.

this is php code for generic meta description:

```
function wpse_custom_meta_description(){
if ( ! is_single() && ! is_page())
return;
$desc = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'description', true );
if( ! empty( $desc ) )
printf(
'<meta name="description" content="%s" />',
esc_attr( trim( $desc ) )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_custom_meta_description' , 2 );
```

...and this is the code for meta description in AMP, but I would like that both formats had the same text, how can I vinculate AMP text to generic?

```
add_action('amp_post_template_head', function() {
    echo '<meta name="description" content="'wpse_custom_meta_description'">';
});
```

I mean, in the AMP php code I need to vinculate to "wpse_custom_meta_description" function.

Thank you!